# What is /bin/red

Tags: server, 18.04

I was trying to access `redis-cli` but because i'm that lazy i typed `red` and hit tab twice, but i noticed that there's a binary actually called `red` which is located under `/bin/`.

When I did

```
cat /bin/red
```

it showed

```
#! /bin/sh
bindir=`echo "$0" | sed -e 's,[^/]*$,,'`
exec "${bindir}"ed --restricted "$@"
```

Any idea what that is?

Note. when i execute `red`, it just waits for an input and whatever i type in, it either ***saves it*** and waits for another prompt or returns `?`, note that only when hitting `q` it exits.
also when inserting numbers from 0-9 and keep enter it shows every input you inserted when ***it saved*** what you typed earlier

example:

```
a <<<-- input
bsa <<< input taken without ?
^C <<<--- hitting ctrl-c
?  <<<--- output
```

example2:

```
v
?
b
?
a
qwrefdf <<-- saved because it didn't output ? after typing "a" up
^C
?
 <<- waiting for input
```

so "h" outputs in "invalid address"
and only "a", "x", "c" and "i" accepts input.
everything else other than numbers results in `?`

Comment: For what it's worth, you could answer this question yourself by running the command `dpkg -S /bin/red`. This will tell you that the file is part of the `ed` package, and `apt-cache show ed` will give you a description of that package.

Comment: Very important : don't execute blindly some application you don't know. Even Linux has malware...

Comment: Ed is the standard text editor. https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html

Comment: Or even more straightforward: `man red`.

Comment: @IMSoP I like how in the joke they made vi ridiculously large at 1.3MB. Fast-forward almost 30 years, and the vim binary on my system is actually twice the joke size at 2.7MB :')

Comment: If you don't know what a file is, especially if it might be binary, it's best to run `file file-name` on it to see what you're dealing with. If it is binary, then running `strings -n 6 file-name | less` will show any printable strings of characters in it that are at least six characters long and put it through a pager because there might be a lot of them. Dumping binary files to a terminal often results in the terminal being reconfigured unpleasantly by "random" strings that happen to match escape sequences the terminal recognizes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`red` is `ed` in restricted mode.

```
$ whatis red
red (1)              - line-oriented text editor

$ man red
shows `ed` man page.
```

Also, the code shows, it executes `ed --restricted` from `bindir` with all arguments (`"$@"`).

For a manual on `ed` and its commands, run `info Ed`.

In the chapter `Invoking ed`:

> The format for running 'ed' is:
>
> ```
>  ed [OPTIONS] [FILE]
>  red [OPTIONS] [FILE]
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> '-r' '--restricted'
>        Run in restricted mode. This mode disables edition of files out of
>        the current directory and execution of shell commands.

Comment: Useful commands for producing some of the information in this answer: `file /bin/red` and `cat /bin/red` (since `file` shows that it's a "POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable).